# Conditional cell disablement in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm using Excel 2007. I want the following behaviour:

- If cell A2 is empty or contains value "Create" then cell B2 is inactive and the user cannot enter a value.
- If cell A2 contains the value "Modify" or "Retire" then cell B2 is active and the user can enter a value.

These behaviours need to be limited to their specific rows, so cell B3 needs to be unaffected by the value in cell A2. These behaviours need to be functional in rows 2 to 501.

I guess that this will require some VBA

Answer (score 0):

2 ways you can persue here I think, either you protect the worksheet and lock those specific cells based on the conditions you stated, or you write a routine for the worksheet_change event.

The first is rather devious I think, so I would opt for the latter.

Something like this perhaps?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'to prevent endless loops
    If Cells(Target.Row, 1) = "Create" Or Cells(Target.Row, 1) = vbNullString Then
        Target.Value = vbNullString
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

All this in the worksheet.

Some explanation:
This sub gets called by Excel whenever the worksheet is changed (hence the name). So if you type a value into any cell, the sub gets called when you leave the cell (hit enter or click another cell, etc).

The `Target` argument in the sub is the range that has just changed.

So if you type `33` in cell B1, `Target` will be `Range("B1")`. So `Target.Column` is the column of the cell that has just changed (in this case, 2), `Target.Row` is the row (1) and `Target.Value` hold the value you just entered (33). So `Cells(Target.Row, 1)` is (in this case) cell A1.

This sub will work for all the rows in the sheet, but I'm sure you can adapt it to check which row it is in.

---

EDIT: added some explanation

Comment: Thanks for that Jzz. Just a newbie question, what do I substitute in Target.Column, Target.Value and Target.Row? So, to be clear, only if cell A2 contains the values "Modify" or "Retire" then cell B2 should be active. In all other cases the cell should be inactive. This behaviour needs to be replicated for all rows right down to row 501. I know I'm asking to be spoon-fed here but I will learn from this! Thanks, Carlos

Comment: modified my answer with some explanation

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (yet not fail proof) would be to create a data validation for the cell by going to data, data-validation, and custom. In the formula input, you could put in

```
=A2<>"Create"
```

if you dont want B2 to be editable if A2 contains "Create". Then you can highlight A2 and B2 and drag it down to row 501. thats the quickest solution that I've stumbled across. Hope this helps